# Android - Check checkbox in 'Custom ListView' using Boolean

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, listview, xamarin

I have a custom listview in my C# Android app, each row contains a textview, ImageView and a checkbox. When a Listview item is clicked, I want to check the row's item checkbox using `bool` value.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
List<TableList> list = = new List<TableList>();
list.Add(new TableList("Germany"));
list.Add(new TableList("France"));
list.Add(new TableList("Finland"));
listView.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string selected = t.Name;
        if (selected == "France")
        {
             Class1.bl = false; // Check the proper checkbox for France row
        }
    };
```

> `Class1.bl` is a static public bool set to `true`

**ListAdapter and ListClass for the Listview:**

```
public class ListAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableList>
{
List<TableList> items;
Activity context;
public ListAdapter(Activity context, List<TableList> items)
    : base()
{
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}
public override long GetItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}
public override TableList this[int position]
{
    get { return items[position]; }
}
public override int Count
{
    get { return items.Count; }
}
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var item = items[position];
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
        view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CoinList, null);
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CoinName).Text = item.Name;
     view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.n);

    if (Class1.bl == false)
        {
            view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Checked = true;
            Class1.bl = true;
        }
        else
        {
            view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Checked = false;
        }
    return view;
  }
 }
public class TableList
{
public string Name;
public TableList(string Name)
{
    this.Name = Name;
}
}
```

The above code when I run it, and I select France, the `ChechBox` is checked for France but when I check another item like Germany, the `ChechBox` for Germany is not checked. Why is this and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Hello, I have provided a demo for you on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewSwitch), the demo works well for me, and I have provide a [gif](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewSwitch/blob/master/screen.gif) to show you the result, also I have record the [screen](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewSwitch/blob/672baeb81bbe29139f98aebe5afea00f554bc052/Video_2018-05-29_110007.wmv) for you. Please test it, if there is any question, please feel free to ask me.

Comment: I don't to use switch anymore. I want to use checkboxes with boolean. @JoeLv-MSFT

Comment: It is the same thing.

Comment: No it is not. I want to use `Boolean`, can it be done with it ?

Comment: Yes, because the logic is the same.

Comment: Great, would you please tell me how to do it with `Boolean` ? @JoeLv-MSFT

Comment: Hello, I have provided the demo on github, please check it.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Your code on github gave me this error in the ListView.ItemClick: here: `var sw = ll.GetChildAt(2) as Switch;` The error is: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: My code is `var sw = ll.GetChildAt(1) as Switch;` not 2.

Comment: Yea, i have tried `var sw = ll.GetChildAt(1) as Switch;` and it didn't worked, so I tried 2 and also didn't worked. I am getting nullEx. @JoeLv-MSFT

Comment: Hi, are you sure that you have downloaded my demo? I have tested it many times, works fine.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Sure I did, I am just getting this exception on `var sw = ll.GetChildAt(1) as Switch;`. What should be the parametere inside the `GetChild()` method ? Maybe i should use another number

Comment: In my project, there are textview and Switch, so the parameter should be 1(0 is TextView). But your result really confuses me. The same project, different results.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Maybe because I have different items in my Layout, I have a checkbox, switch, textview , imageview and a linear layout. So I should change the parameter inside the `GetChildAt()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add the bool in your `TableList` class:

```
//I add the bool in this class, so you can change the CheckBox's state by your Data Source
//That means that your CheckBox's state based upon your Data Source.
public class TableList : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TableList(string name, bool b)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.bl = b;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool bl { get; set; }
}
```

I also provide the demo on the [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewCheckBox), and [here](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewCheckBox/blob/master/dapao.gif) is the result gif.

Comment: That's wont work, cause I am adding items to the ListView outside of the `ListView.ItemClick`and I want to ckeck the Listview item on `ItemClick`. Review my code.

Comment: I am getting Nullexception at ` if (cb.Checked)` in the `ListView.ItemClick` and I think it is caused by this `GetChildAt(2)`. Plus, I have tried all numbers from0 to 4 but every time I get the same exception. So I am thinking that maybe the `RelativeLayout ll` is the cause, since I have multiple Layouts.

Comment: You can use `for(int i=0;i<)` to get every child, and check it's type.

Comment: I have used this `var cb = ll.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);` instead of `GetChildAt(2)` and it is working!!

Comment: I need to re-check user checked items from previous time (so he does not need to check them each time he opens the app, they will be stored and checked in the listview). Can you help me to do so ?